# Discrete LTI systems with complex inputs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, control-theory, z-transform

I'm reading and pondereing about the convolution sumation, properties and how this is related to discrete LTI systems.

I'm using the book Signals and Systems by Alan V. Oppenheim, and on the chapter 3.2 "Response of LTI Systems to complex exponentials" we start using as inputs for the Systems complex exponentials of the form :

$$
z^n \rightarrow H(z)z^n
$$

And it is defined the same as in a convolution of a real valued input signal $x[n]$ to a sistem with impulse response $h[n]$

$$
y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{x[k]h[n-k]}
$$

Due to the conmutativity of the convolution :

$$
y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{x[n]h[n-k]} = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{h[k]x[n-k]}
$$
$$
y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{h[k]z^{n-k}} = z^{n}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{h[k]z^{-k}} 
$$

I get the idea that the System is behaving as a linear system for complex input signals, how ever **I dont understand why using complex valued signals** as inputs.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  I haven't read this book, but in general you're right that complex input signals make no mathematical difference -- the system is still LTI.  As to _why_ they might be useful, imagine your input is a sinusoid, then it is often much easier to deal with it as the sum of two complex exponentials (or the real / imag part of a single complex exponential) instead of directly dealing with the sinusoid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get why it's easier to work with sines and cosines in complex polar coordinates, but why is this usefull if my inputs are step funtions or ramps. Doesn't this makes my well defined functions in discrete time, as infinite sums in complex exponential basis ?

Comment: I imagine the book eventually wants to get there, maybe?  I.e. turn everything into the transformed domain.  Maybe if you read ahead, you will find out.  :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the simplification in the calculation of the convolution is the main goal of using complex exponentials as a basis for a linear combination of the system inputs.